# Text flowing from div to div

Tags: jquery, html, css, text

I need some divs in which the text automatically flows from one to another. While css regions are still unripe, I found this trick to simulate the effect: https://jsfiddle.net/9o4ebbfL/1/

The trick is valid, but there's an annoying empty space at the beginning of the first div. How can i remove it? Curiously, the original fiddle from which i drew my example (http://jsfiddle.net/natedavisolds/bxzCK/16/) has no additional space, despite the fact that the code is the same.

```
<html lang="it">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.column {
     width: 150px;
     height: 200px;
     overflow:hidden;
     float:left;
     border: 1px solid #cccccc;
     padding: 0px 20px;   
     margin: 10px;    
    }
.column .content {
     line-height: 20px;   
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="column1" class="column">
   <div class="content">
    <p>One plus one is equal to two. Two plus two is equal to four. Three plus three is equal to six. Four plus four is equal to eight. Five plus five is equal to ten. Six plus six is equal to twelve. Seven plus seven is equal to fourteen. Eight plus eight is equal to sixteen. Nine plus nine is equal to eighteen. Ten plus ten is equal to twenty. Eleven plus eleven is equal to twenty-two.</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="column" data-overflow="#column1">

<script>
$('.column[data-overflow]').each(function(index) {
    var $this = $(this),
        $parent = $($this.data('overflow')),
        colHeight = $parent.innerHeight(),
        scroll = parseInt(colHeight) * (index + 1),
        newHeight = "-=" + scroll + "px";

    $this.html($parent.html())
         .find('.content').css({ marginTop: newHeight});

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: now please check =>https://jsfiddle.net/9o4ebbfL/14/

Comment: Mr. Mehta, you have not got the point. I need the text flowing from one div to another, not repeating itself twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to normalize your CSS in JSFiddle. Click on the CSS cog in the top-right of the CSS section, and tick **Normalized CSS**:

[image: How to normalize CSS in JSFiddle]

[Explanation](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html?highlight=normalized#choose-framework):

> Normalized CSS:
>   A checkbox, deselected by default. If selected, the fiddle will be rendered with normalize.css which is removing most of the browser styling of many HTML tags.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not solve the problem in my offline html page.

Comment: You will need to add normalize.css to your offline html page then :)

Comment: I've added normalize.css to my page. No result, the blank space is still there. In jsfiddle, the normalization works, however. What am i doing wrong? This is the zip with all my files, if needed: https://files.fm/u/c4de9b62.

Comment: Ok, i solved utilizing reset.css instead of normalize.css. Thanks.